# Is OAuth 2.0 A Concept or a Tangible Framework you must download?

Tags: .net, api, oauth

I'm somewhat confused about what you would professionally call an "OAuth 2.0" Authentication system...

I've already built an MVC RESTful API interface that stores its username and password values in an SQL Server as it's model.

So whenever a user logs into my service by visiting POST:`http://example.com/api/login`, that URL simply returns a JSON containing an access token belonging to the user you logged in as.

Once you have an access token of a particular username you've logged in as, you could then do something that requires user privledges such as for example:
POST:`http://example.com/api/createRecord`

So can you build OAuth 2.0 from scratch or is there more to OAuth than just the concept of access tokens?

Comment: [It's a standard.](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, a client application gets an access token by presenting a user's credentials (ID & password) to /api/login. On the other hand, OAuth 2.0 is a framework where a user of a service can allow a third-party client application to access his/her data hosted in the service **without revealing his/her credentials (ID & password) to the application**. The current implementation of your service is not capable of allowing a third-party client application to access your service unless a user of your service passes his/her credentials to the application.

Understand the point described above and read [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), and you will find OAuth 2.0 is a specification that you'll need to implement.